# gapi.auth.authorize "Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined"

Tags: typescript, google-api, google-api-js-client

I'm running this code, somethimes i get an error, others i don't and i can't really understand why.

```
let promiseLogIn = new Promise(function(reject,resolve){
  gapi.auth.authorize(authData , function(response) {
      var authButton = document.getElementById('auth-button');
      if (response.error) {
        console.log("AuthBad");
        resolve();
        authButton.hidden = false;
      }
      else {
        console.log("AuthGood");
        reject();
        authButton.hidden = true;
      }
    });
  });
```

i load the lib in my html file like this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>
<script src="sources/scripts/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

where bundle.j is where i have all the compiled ts files.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to tag this under typescript?

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the gapi library correctly?

Comment: @Aron this is built using typescript, how should i load it correctly?

Comment: @Aron in my html i have:
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>
<script src="sources/scripts/dist/bundle.js"></script>

where bundle.js is ths Ts compiled

Comment: Please edit your question with the script tags too

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are getting this error because you do not have the `auth2` library in scope. To add libraries to your google scope, Google's sample documentation encourages loading of new packages using the [gapi.load()](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs) method. So, here's how you can do it:

```
let promiseLogIn = new Promise(function(reject,resolve){
  gapi.load('auth2', function(){
    gapi.auth.authorize(authData , function(response) {
      var authButton = document.getElementById('auth-button');
      if (response.error) {
        console.log("AuthBad");
        resolve();
        authButton.hidden = false;
      }
      else {
        console.log("AuthGood");
        reject();
        authButton.hidden = true;
      }
    });
  });
});
```